# How would I make this really complicated inheritance tree

Tags: c++, inheritance

Okay. So I'm in a situation in which I have a very complicated inheritance tree, (I swear it's  legitimate). I'm not going to go into the details of what the classes contain because that is irrelevant to my question.

```
      A<-D
     /|  |
    / |  |
   B  |  |
    \ |  |
     \|  |
      C  |
       \ |
        \|
         E
```

So far the inheritance is as follows.

```
class A 
{
    int data;
    ...
};

class B: public A {...};
class C: public A, public B {...};
```

I want C to have twice to instances of A, so I don't use virtual inheritance. However, I want class E to only inherit `C::B::A::data` and `C::A::data` and not `D::A::data`. I know I have to implement virtual inheritance in some way, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: C has two instances of A::data. I want E to inherit the same two from C, and inherit no instances of A::data from D

Comment: If you move `D` upwards to be horizontally aligned with `A`, then the pattern will look like a half-full bathtub and we can properly call it the Bathtup Inheritance Pattern.

Comment: A sideways bathtub sort of...

Comment: Which of the two instances of A do you want D to virtually inherit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look around here you'll find some detailed discussions about virtual inheritance, particularly what happens when you combine virtual and normal inheritance.

I've got code which I think creates the hierarchy you've described, but be forewarned: it won't link on OS X.  It compiles fine, but I get some truly unusual undefined symbols.

The main thing of note is that it's difficult to get to certain base classes when you mix virtual and non-virtual inheritance.  To resolve this I've added another layer anywhere virtual inheritance is required.  That layer can then provide uniquely named accessors.  This is accomplished with the Virtualize template.

I'd love to know if this confuses other compilers:

```
#include <cstdio>

template<class OnType,class UniqueType>
class Virtualize : public virtual OnType
{
public:
    inline OnType &resolve() { return *this; }
};

class A
{
public:
    A(int data): m_aData((data << 4) | 0x0A)
    {
        printf("Constructed A(%X)\n",m_aData);
    }

    A();

    virtual ~A()
    {
        printf("Destructing A(%X)\n",m_aData);
    }

    int m_aData;
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B(int data): m_bData((data<<4) | 0x0B),
                 A((data<<4) | 0x0B)
    {
        printf("Constructed B(%X)\n",m_bData);
    }

    virtual ~B()
    {
        printf("Destructing B(%X)\n",m_bData);
    }

    A &getBsA() { return *this; }
    int m_bData;
};

class C: public Virtualize<A,C>,
         public B
{
public:
    C(int data): A((data<<4) | 0x0C),
                 B((data<<4) | 0x0C),
                 m_cData((data<<4) | 0x0C)
    {
        printf("Constructed C(%X)\n",m_cData);
    }

    virtual ~C()
    {
        printf("Destructing C(%X)\n",m_cData);
    }

    A &getCsA() { return Virtualize<A,C>::resolve(); }

    int m_cData;
};

class D: public Virtualize<A,D>
{
public:
    D(int data): m_dData((data<<4) | 0x0D),
                 A((data<<4) | 0x0D)
    {
        printf("Constructed D(%X)\n",data);
    }

    virtual ~D()
    {
        printf("Constructed D(%X)\n",m_dData);
    }

    A &getDsA() { return Virtualize<A,D>::resolve(); }

    int m_dData;
};

class E: public C, public D, public Virtualize<A,E>
{
public:
    E(int data): A((data<<4) | 0x0E),
                 C((data<<4) | 0x0E),
                 D((data<<4) | 0x0E),
                 m_eData((data<<4) | 0x0E)
    {
        printf("Constructed E(%X)\n",m_eData);
    }

    virtual ~E()
    {
        printf("Destructing E(%X)\n",m_eData);
    }

    A &getEsA() { return Virtualize<A,E>::resolve(); }

    int m_eData;
};

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    E e(0);

    printf("E::B::A::m_aData = %X\n",e.getBsA().m_aData);
    printf("E::C::A::m_aData = %X\n",e.getCsA().m_aData);
    printf("E::D::A::m_aData = %X\n",e.getDsA().m_aData);
    printf("E::E::A::m_aData = %X\n",e.getEsA().m_aData);

    C c(0);

    printf("C::B::A::m_aData = %X\n",c.getBsA().m_aData);
    printf("C::A::m_aData = %X\n",c.getCsA().m_aData);

    return 0;
}
```

For the interested I get these issues during the link phase:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      _main in cc6nOq3n.o
      D::~D()    in cc6nOq3n.o
      D::~D()    in cc6nOq3n.o
      D::D(int)  in cc6nOq3n.o
      B::~B()    in cc6nOq3n.o
      B::~B()    in cc6nOq3n.o
      B::~B()    in cc6nOq3n.o
      ...
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Ain cc6nOq3n.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Din cc6nOq3n.o
      typeinfo for Bin cc6nOq3n.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for Virtualize<A, E>in cc6nOq3n.o
      typeinfo for Virtualize<A, D>in cc6nOq3n.o
      typeinfo for Virtualize<A, C>in cc6nOq3n.o
      typeinfo for Cin cc6nOq3n.o
      typeinfo for Ein cc6nOq3n.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
  "operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      A::~A()    in cc6nOq3n.o
      A::~A()    in cc6nOq3n.o
      A::~A()    in cc6nOq3n.o
      Virtualize<A, E>::~Virtualize()in cc6nOq3n.o
      Virtualize<A, E>::~Virtualize()in cc6nOq3n.o
      Virtualize<A, D>::~Virtualize()in cc6nOq3n.o
      Virtualize<A, D>::~Virtualize()in cc6nOq3n.o
      ...
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      Dwarf Exception Unwind Info (__eh_frame) in cc6nOq3n.o
```

Comment: I really like this solution because it was exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately I want portability and those errors are scary. I can definitely see myself using Virtualize at some point. Thank you so much for your answer

Comment: It's possible that I was using the wrong command line (gcc vs. g++).  Google seems to relate these errors to that.

Answer (score 1):

`D::A::data` is part and parcel of `D`. You cannot inherit `D` without getting a `D::A::data`. If you have a reference to any `D`, then you also have a means of access to its `D::A::data`.

Sounds like you need to split `D` into two classes, or otherwise redesign the part we're not seeing.

Let me rephrase this: `D::A::data` needs to go to *something*, and this question is impossible to answer unless we know what that is. What does the implementation of `D` see when it is a subobject of `E` and it accesses `data`?

Comment: maybe. But if you do virtual inheritance in the Diamond Inheritance Dilemma, you only get one instance of the base class

Comment: @bathtub You get one instance of the base class for all the virtual bases in the hierarchy. In this case there is only one such potential base, so it won't make a difference. (And you already know that, or you wouldn't be asking the question.)

Comment: Well I only knew how virtual inheritance worked in the classic diamond problem. Oh well. Pure virtual base class time. Looks like this tree is getting more complicated. And D publicly inherits A as of now